# How to create a cmdlet with different parameterset?

Tags: powershell

I have created a powershell module with two cmdlets with the same name and having different parameter names.

I thought it will have 2 cmdlet with different parameter sets. But it is not the case it seems.

Is there any way that we can have different parameter set for same cmdlet ?

Comment: Does  `ParameterSetName` from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847743.aspx not satisfy this requirement? If these cmdlets do two _completely_ separate things should they not have different names?

Answer (score -1):

You totally shouldn't be making two cmdlets with the same name.  Try to work around this problem by modifying the noun name.  For instance, if you have two modules, one for Prod and one for Test, both of which have a cmdlet named Start-Foo, you should name the cmdlets Start-ProdFoo and Start-TestFoo to avoid the name overlap.

Now, if for some strange and historical reason you simply must create two cmdlets with the same name, you can get to the other cmdlet by providng the module name first, like so:

```
ModuleName\Start-Prod
```